# Removing stickers from the door

Tags: paint, cleaning

My kids put some stickers on the wall.
[image]

I am thinking of using De-Solve-it to easily take off the stickers.

https://www.google.com.au/shopping/product/15260427858274158749?lsf=seller:100794174,store:13368512415747446475&prds=oid:6742449688119855807&q=sticker+remover&hl=en&ei=vrsJXpWkKs29rQHdzoOgBw&lsft=gclid:CjwKCAiA3abwBRBqEiwAKwICA4VH6ef0y5fDkUbtgLgK1Rp0mv9KAL8uUHyjbZyo3yJ0D6XoXichmhoCo6kQAvD_BwE,gclsrc:aw.ds

but worried if it may affect the paint

Is it safe? is there another easy way to remove the stickers without buying special products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use de solve it it is good stuff, I have not had it affect any surface I have used it on but I am usually working on removing adhesive from painted metal.

I would try an area out of site first and rub a little to see if it affects the paint, it will definitely help clean the adhesive off but the only way to know for sure on your paint is to try it in a area that would not be noticed.